# Translate API now failing - returns

Tags: google-translate

Here is the code:

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script'); 
newScript.type = 'text/javascript'; 
var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML); 
var source = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyC24dCfm2u_pdXO3KOSBNdq0cBYJubKyS8&source=zh-CN&target=zh-TW&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
newScript.src = source; 

// When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off. 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
```

It used to return Chinese Traditional from Chinese Simplified in the **sourceText** variable. Now it returns the below.

Can anyone let me know what changed at Google to throw this offbase?
regards. TIM

sourceText:

> Cobalt Blue Holdings Limited (ASX:COB) 2017年3月季度活动和现金流报告

returned text from the Translate API:

> Cobalt Blue Holdings Limited (ASX:COB) 2017%u5E743%u6708%u5B63%u5EA6%u6D3B%u52A8%u548C%u73B0%u91D1%u6D41%u62A5%u544A

Comment: Can you re-try to see if it works? Also you can try the API Explorer to see if it works as expected: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/translate/v2/language.translations.list

Answer (score 0):

Just directly in my browser your sample works.

- [Translate to English.](https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyC24dCfm2u_pdXO3KOSBNdq0cBYJubKyS8&source=zh-CN&target=en&callback=translateText&q=Cobalt%20Blue%20Holdings%20Limited%20(ASX:COB)%202017%E5%B9%B43%E6%9C%88%E5%AD%A3%E5%BA%A6%E6%B4%BB%E5%8A%A8%E5%92%8C%E7%8E%B0%E9%87%91%E6%B5%81%E6%8A%A5%E5%91%8A).
- [Translate to Taiwanese](https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyC24dCfm2u_pdXO3KOSBNdq0cBYJubKyS8&source=zh-CN&target=zh-TW&callback=translateText&q=Cobalt%20Blue%20Holdings%20Limited%20(ASX:COB)%202017%E5%B9%B43%E6%9C%88%E5%AD%A3%E5%BA%A6%E6%B4%BB%E5%8A%A8%E5%92%8C%E7%8E%B0%E9%87%91%E6%B5%81%E6%8A%A5%E5%91%8A).

I'm guessing you need to decode the output coming back from the API. For example, the response u544A should map to [this UTF character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/544a/index.htm).

Is there any reason you're raw curling the API call?  There are [API client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries) that should manage this for you.

Also, you might want to revoke your API key as you have posted it publicly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This was set up a while ago, and Google changed the endpoint recently for this.. What I cannot find is, what changed in order that the response is now being delivered in Unicode entities. Yes, the API key was a blooper I realized a second after I submitted the post, thanks for that reminder. I will try and implement decoding on the client to see what happens.